# UIWebView that shows specific place of Page

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a very simple `UIWebView` that I would like to show only a select place of the HTML Page. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an anchor ( HTML tag )

Mark certain position of page by adding:

```
<a name="someAnchor"> </a>
```

and call it by:

```
<a href="#someAnchor">Click here to jump to certain position</a>
```

Comment: I've never used an HTML tag. Sorry if this is asking too much. but could you give me a more detailed description of how to impliment this? like. how do i mark a certain point of the page? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code when web view finishes loading

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.scrollTop = %d", chkScrollValue]];
```

where chkScrollValue is the position of your content in webview.

Comment: how would i go about defining the chkScrolValue?

Comment: i use below code on button click to get chkScrolValue                      int scrollPosition = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];   If you don want to do this you can just use try and error give random value like 200 see the output and then set this value according to what you like.